# How to implement io_manager that have a parameter at asset level?

Tags: python, parquet, dagster

I am a bit confused about the usage of resources, configuration and how they are linked to a context and an asset.

So I have a parquet io manager that is able to manipulate and partitionned not-partitionned datasets.
To do so I check the presence of a partition on the context in the `self._get_path()` method and provide a unique name for each file, using the key of the asset and a date format of the partition.

```py
# from dagter examples
if context.has_asset_partitions:
    end = context.asset_partitions_time_window
```

Now I have an issue if the same asset is used with different paritions sizes because the names not necesserally are the same during the reading and writing of the files. *e.g.* I have some 1h partitions asset and some 1d partitions asset using the same base asset.

The solution to this, IMO is to use the `filters` kwargs from `pandas.read_parquet`, that would allow me to get only the data inside the time window of the partition.
So I want to provide a string parameter to my io manager for it to know which column has to be used to filter the partition interval.

This parameter is obviously linked to an asset.

I could add this as a parameter of my io_manger constructor and create one instance of io_manager per different column name. But I find it cumbersome and my intuition tells me that I should be using the InputContext to retrieve this information. (the same way I am using the context to get the start,end of the partition)

So maybe I should create a ConfigurableResource with only one string attribute (the time column's name), instantiate one object per different column name and provide it to the asset construction (via required_resource_keys?). If this is the right solution, how can I access to the ressource in the io_manager?

Or is there any other parameter of the asset constructor that I should be using to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the following IO manager:

```py
class PartitionedParquetIOManager(IOManager):
    def __init__(self, base_path: str, time_column: str = 'timestamp'):
        self._base_path = Path(base_path)
        self.time_column = time_column

    def load_input(self, context: InputContext) -> pandas.DataFrame:
        path = self._get_path(context)
        filters = self._get_filters(context)

        context.log.debug(f'Reading from {path} with filters {filters}')

        return pandas.read_parquet(path, filters=filters)

    def _get_filters(self, context: InputContext) -> List[Tuple[str, str, Any]]:
        filters = []
        start, end = context.asset_partitions_time_window

        # wierd casting to be able to use those in a filter
        start = dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(start.timestamp(), pytz.timezone(start.tz.name))
        end = dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(end.timestamp(), pytz.timezone(end.tz.name))

        filters.extend([(self.time_column, '>=', start), (self.time_column, '<', end)])
        return filters
```

A function needs to be created so it can be used in the `@asset(io_manager_def=`.

```py
@io_manager(
    config_schema={"data_path": Field(str, is_required=False), "time_column": Field(str, is_required=False)},
)
def local_partitioned_parquet_io_manager(init_context):
    fallback_path = os.getenv('DAGSTER_ROOT_DATA_FOLDER', get_system_temp_directory())
    return PartitionedParquetIOManager(
        base_path=init_context.resource_config.get("data_path", fallback_path),
        time_column=init_context.resource_config.get('time_column', 'timestamp')
    )
```

Then the asset can be created with

```py
@asset(io_manager_def=local_partitioned_parquet_io_manager.configured({'time_column': 'timestamp'}),
       partitions_def=six_hours_partitions_30h_offset)
def my_custom_df(context) -> pd.DataFrame:
    start, end = context.asset_partitions_time_window_for_output()

    df = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp': pd.date_range(start, end, freq='5T', tz=pytz.timezone('Europe/Brussels'))})
    df['count'] = df['timestamp'].map(lambda _:  random.randint(1, 1000))
    return df


@asset(io_manager_def=local_partitioned_parquet_io_manager,
       partitions_def=daily_partitions)
def another_custom_df(context, my_custom_df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    return my_custom_df.set_index('timestamp').resample('H').agg({'count': 'mean'}).reset_index()
```

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get this working, but I still think that I am missing something.

With this, a user could easily break the IO Manager by not providing the resource definition `TimeColConfig`.

```py
import pandas as pd
from dagster import Config, Field, asset
import dagster


class TimeColConfig(Config):
    time_col: str = Field(
        config=dagster.String,
        description="The name of the time column against which the partitions will be filtered",
        default_value='timestamp'
    )

@asset(io_manager_def='parquet_io_manager',
       partitions_def=hourly_partitions)
def my_custom_df(context) -> pd.DataFrame:
    start, end = context.asset_partitions_time_window_for_output()

    df = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp': pd.date_range(start, end, freq='5T')})
    df['count'] = df['timestamp'].map(lambda a:  random.randint(1, 1000))
    return df


@asset(io_manager_def='parquet_io_manager',
       partitions_def=daily_partitions,
       resource_defs={'io_config': TimeColConfig(time_col='timestamp')})
def another_custom_df(context, my_custom_df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    return my_custom_df.set_index('timestamp').resample('H').agg({'count': 'mean'})


class PartitionedParquetIOManager(IOManager):
    def load_input(self, context: InputContext) -> pandas.DataFrame:
        path = self._get_path(context)
        filters = self._get_filters(context)
        return pandas.read_parquet(path, filters=filters)

    def _get_filters(self, context: InputContext) -> List[Tuple[str, str, Any]]:
        filters = []
        
        start, end = context.asset_partitions_time_window
        time_col = context.step_context.resources.io_config.time_col
        filters.append((time_col, '>=', start), (time_col, '<', end))
        return filters
```